# before_destroy callback in Rails 5 throw(:abort) but also modify record

Tags: callback, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5, I believe the only way to prevent destroy is to call `throw(:abort)`; and this is working as expected. The issue I am having, however, is if the record does not meet requirements, rather than destroying it I want to modify the record. However with `throw(:abort)`  the entire transaction is reverted, undoing any changes the record has received.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord

  before_destroy :can_destroy?

  private

  def can_destroy?
    if model.something?
      self.update(something: 'foo') # This part is not being retained.
      throw(:abort)
  end
end
```

Comment: The reason why this is happening is because ActiveRecord wraps the before/after callbacks in SQL transactions, and so when the transaction fails the update is rolled back.

Comment: Yea I get that, but in R4 you could just do `return false` and what I am trying to achieve would be possible. I'm just wondering what a sane way of achieving this in R5 would be.

Comment: I gave this my best shot, but if you find a neater way to do this, I'd be happy to hear it :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're encountering is that ActiveRecord wraps all of your before/after callbacks in transactions to ensure that if any of them fail, no results will be committed to the database. Sadly, you want to do exactly what it's trying to protect you from. There isn't really a "good" way of doing this (that I'm aware of) but a bit of a hack to get around this restriction would be to do your update in an `after_rollback` callback, because your `throw(:abort)` will cause a transaction rollback. For example:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord

  before_destroy :can_destroy?
  after_rollback :can_destroy_callbacks
  private

  def can_destroy?
    if model.something?
      @update_later = true
      throw(:abort)
    end
  end

  def can_destroy_callbacks
    if @update_later
      update(something: 'foo')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. In my case I think i'm just gonna handle this at the controller level as I don't want this happening upon _any_ rollback. I guess I mainly just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking something here. Thanks for the input!

Comment: If you want to look into this a bit further, there are pleanty of soft-delete gems, which also need to solve this problem somehow.